# See which issues had their severity changed

Tags: sonarqube

In Sonarqube (I use version 4.5.1), a user can change the severity of an issue (I don't mean changing the severity of a Rule). So in theory, a developer could take a "critical" issue and change it to a "minor".

A project lead or reviewer might want to know which issues had their severity changed but it is not clear to me how she could see that. (For false positives on the other hand, there is a widget called "False Positives Issues" that shows clearly which issues were marked as false positive).

Comment: I noticed that only an administrator can change the severity of an issue. While I still think the question is relevant, this makes it less critical.

Answer (score 0):

For SonarQube v4.5.1 there is the [Viewing an Issue change log](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/SONAR/Reviewing+Issues#ReviewingIssues-ViewinganIssuechangelog) that can be used to see if an issue has changed its severity.

Additional there is the [Widget Plan Plugin](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/SONAR/Widget+Lab+Plugin) that can show Manual Severity Reviews, but it's not working for SonarQube 3.6+. I have tried the plugin, both in SonarQube v4.5.1 and in v3.5.1, and its only working in v.3.5.1.

Hope this helps you.

Comment: Thanks for the valuable information, although the Issue change log is only useful to inspect a limited number of issues (and not the thousands that might exist in a project). I might raise this as an issue in the SonarSource's JIRA.